# Batch crawling youtube search

Tags: powershell, batch-file, youtube, web-crawler, batch-processing

I have project to school to make batch script + powershell.
So my idea was to ask user about video he want to see in youtube.

I ask user about video, I can make it search. I run powershell to wget yt.com/results?search_query=**Something** and I save it.

After this I have to find for first video in the list, so I need batch to find it. I tried FINDSTR but I cannot make it useful.

I found in code something that is showing up only 1 time and I know it's my video so I need to find:

```
FINDSTR "<a aria-hidden=\"true\"  href=*" something.html > result.txt
```

> so **' *  '** because we don't know link, and something.html is
>   yt.com/results?search_query=**Something**

Sadly it dosen't work as I want. I get too long result in totally wrong place (too far). How can I make it work?

*Maybe there is other way to run 1st video after search?*

Answer (score 0):

Your variables and command would be as follows within PowerShell

```
$var = Read-Host 'Search for video'
$var = $var -replace ' ','+'

Invoke-RestMethod -uri “https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?v=2&q=$var” | 
foreach {[PSCustomObject]@{Title=$_.Title; Author=$_.author.name; Link=$_.content.src}} | Format-List
```